# подключить canvas анимацию ко vue проекту

Tags: javascript, vue.js, canvas

хочу в своем проекте подключить анимацию [https://codepen.io/at80/pen/tqdmv][1]
как это реализовать во вью?

Answer (score 1):

1. с канвасом просто - подключаем через ref и mounted.
2. в html есть скрипт шейдеров, его полностью надо скопировать и вставить в public/index.html.
3. css, думаю тоже не составит проблем
4. с js два варианта. первый - обернуть в глобальную функцию, типа

   window.sakura = () => { ... }

и вызывать в mounted

```
mounted: () => {
  window.sakura();
}
```

либо перенести весь в код в компонент в methods